# OpenGL glTexParameteri error 0x0500

Tags: c++, opengl

This line of code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

generate error `0x0500` (GL_INVALID_ENUM), but all the rendering process works as before. What could be the problem and how could it be solved ?

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid GL context while calling this? And are you sure that the GL error was actually _generated_ by this call, and not some earlier one?

Comment: yes, it is created with if `if (!gladLoadGL())` and it all work fine , just this error, but nothing go wrong with the actual rendering.

Comment: @derhass is right: `glGenBuffers` can't generate this error, so it should have been generated earlier in your code. Call `glGetError` **before** your `glGenBuffers` line. If available on your OpenGL implementation, take also a look to [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) feature

Comment: My error, the error seems to be generated by one of these `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [error value 0x500 is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors). That means you have passed an enumeration to a function where that enum is not a valid parameter.

`GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is not a valid `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` option.

Comment: Thank you ! It was just a very stupid mistake, trying to set a maximum filter on mipmap, so I just removed the line, and for the minimum filter, i used GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR